# Reading a .txt file with numbers

Tags: import

The .txt file is:

tb_FeSe_22_12_2014.csv  0.00102786

(-0.000421863,1.58589e-09)(-4.04766e-05,2.67116e-07)(-8.4396e-06,-1.54976e-07)

I would like to Import it to Mathematica such that I have:

```
a=0.00102786;

b={-0.000421863+I*1.58589*10^-09,-4.04766*10^-05+I*2.67116*10^-07,-8.4396*10^-06+I*-1.54976*10^-07};
```

I tried to "Import", and then "StringReplace" to try to create an array, but I did not achieve anything. I think that part of the difficulty comes from the fact that the numbers in the .txt are not separated by comas.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected with 2012rcampion's feedback

```
    data = Import["test.txt"]
    (*"(-0.000421863,1.58589e-09)(-4.04766e-05,2.67116e-07)(-8.4396e-06,-1.\
    54976e-07)
    (-0.000421863,1.58589e-09)(-4.04766e-05,2.67116e-07)(-8.4396e-06,-1.\
    54976e-07)"*)

    data = ToExpression[
     StringSplit[
      StringReplace[data, {","->"+I*","(" -> "", "e" -> "*^"}], {",", ")"}]]

(*{-0.000421863 + 1.58589*10^-9 I, -0.0000404766 + 
  2.67116*10^-7 I, -8.4396*10^-6 - 1.54976*10^-7 I, -0.000421863 + 
  1.58589*10^-9 I, -0.0000404766 + 2.67116*10^-7 I, -8.4396*10^-6 - 
  1.54976*10^-7 I}*)
```

Comment: Thanks @Zviovich , but the output is not the one I want (named as b in the post)

Comment: Try `StringSplit[StringReplace[data, {"," -> "+I*", "e" -> "*^"}], ("(" | ")") ..]`

Comment: Thanks @2012rcampion, it creates an array, but Mathematica treats the elements as strings, not as numbers. How can I fix that?

Comment: @mencia if you look at the answer that I updated with 2012rcampion feedback you can see that there is a ToExpression command which makes it a complex number. Check with Head[#]&/@data which returns {Complex, Complex, Complex, Complex, Complex, Complex}